# How to use a JSON inside an apex class?

Tags: apex, integration, json

Main Class:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/updateFaturamento/*')
global  class contractFat { 

    public class ContractJSON {

        public List<Contract> Contract;

        public class Contract {
            public String idSalesForce;
            public String dtEmissao;
            public String nrContrato;
            public String vlVenda;
            public String vlDevolucao;
            public String qtTotalClientes;
            public String qtClientesAtivosMes;
            public String flagMensal;
        }


        public  ContractJSON parse(String json) {
            return (ContractJSON) System.JSON.deserialize(json, ContractJSON.class);
        }
    }
    @HttpPatch
    global static String updateFaturamento(String contractId,Integer nrContrato, Boolean flagMensal, Double vlVenda, Double vlDevolucao,
                                              integer qtTotalClientes, integer qtClientesAtivosMes, Date dtEmissao ){
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request; 
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;

        if (flagMensal == false){

            Opportunity oppInsert = [SELECT Id,Data_Emissao__c, Numero_Contrato_Univers__c, Valor_Vendas__c, Valor_Devolucao__c, 
                                             Quantidade_Total_Clientes__c, Quantidade_Cliente_Ativos_Mes__c 
                                             from Opportunity WHERE ContractId  =: contractId and Numero_Contrato_Univers__c =: nrContrato];

            //if (oppInsert.Numero_Contrato_Univers__c == null ){}

            oppInsert.Data_Emissao__c = dtEmissao;
            oppInsert.Numero_Contrato_Univers__c = nrContrato;
            oppInsert.Valor_Vendas__c = vlVenda;
            oppInsert.Valor_Devolucao__c = vlDevolucao;
            oppInsert.Quantidade_Total_Clientes__c = qtTotalClientes;
            oppInsert.Quantidade_Cliente_Ativos_Mes__c = qtClientesAtivosMes;

            upsert oppInsert ;

            return 'Faturamento';           

        } else if (flagMensal == true) {
            Contract contractInsert = [SELECT Id, Data_Emissao__c, Valor_Vendas__c, Valor_Devolucao__c, Quantidade_Total_Clientes__c,
                                             Quantidade_Clientes_Ativos_Mes__c  from Contract WHERE Id =: contractId];

            contractInsert.Data_Emissao__c = dtEmissao;
            contractInsert.Valor_Vendas__c = vlVenda;
            contractInsert.Valor_Devolucao__c = vlDevolucao;
            contractInsert.Quantidade_Total_Clientes__c = qtTotalClientes;
            contractInsert.Quantidade_Clientes_Ativos_Mes__c = qtClientesAtivosMes;

            upsert ContractInsert;

            /*List<Opportunity> listOpportunity = [select  ContractId, Id, Numero_Contrato_Univers__c, Data_Emissao__c, Valor_Vendas__c, 
                                                        Valor_Devolucao__c, Quantidade_Total_Clientes__c, Quantidade_Cliente_Ativos_Mes__c 
                                                        from Opportunity where ContractId =: contractId and  Numero_Contrato_Univers__c =: nrContrato ];

            for(Opportunity opp : listOpportunity){
                Opportunity oppDeleteDiario = new Opportunity ();
                oppDeleteDiario.Data_Emissao__c = dtEmissao;
                oppDeleteDiario.Valor_Vendas__c = vlVenda;
                oppDeleteDiario.Valor_Devolucao__c = vlDevolucao;
                oppDeleteDiario.Quantidade_Total_Clientes__c = qtTotalClientes;
                oppDeleteDiario.Quantidade_Cliente_Ativos_Mes__c = qtClientesAtivosMes;

                delete oppDeleteDiario; 
                return 'Deleted';
            }       */

            Opportunity oppDelete = [SELECT Id,Data_Emissao__c, Numero_Contrato_Univers__c, Valor_Vendas__c, Valor_Devolucao__c, 
                                             Quantidade_Total_Clientes__c, Quantidade_Cliente_Ativos_Mes__c 
                                             from Opportunity WHERE ContractId  =: contractId and Numero_Contrato_Univers__c =: nrContrato];

            //oppDelete.Data_Emissao__c = dtEmissao;
            //oppDelete.Numero_Contrato_Univers__c = nrContrato;
            oppDelete.Valor_Vendas__c = null;
            oppDelete.Valor_Devolucao__c = null;
            oppDelete.Quantidade_Total_Clientes__c = null;
            oppDelete.Quantidade_Cliente_Ativos_Mes__c = null;

            delete oppDelete;                        

            return 'Faturamento Mensal  Updated';
        }    
        return null;
    }
}
```

Hi everyone, I'm new to Salesforce and need to get a JSON to put inside my Apex class as per the code above.
However it presents the following error:

> Inner types are not allowed to have inner types

(in excerpt of the code:

```
public class Contract {
    public String idSalesForce;
    public String dtEmissao;
    public String nrContract;
    public String vlVenda;
    public String vlDevolution;
    public String qtTotalClients;
    public String qtClientActiveMes;
    public String flagMensal;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you have three classes in the same class - an inner class can't have another inner class inside of it. You can move the innermost class out, or into its own file.

Wont Compile:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/updateFaturamento/*')
global class contractFat {
    // inner class 
    public class ContractJSON {

        public List<Contract> Contract;
        // inner class inside an inner class - failure ! 
        public class Contract { 
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Will Compile:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/updateFaturamento/*')
global class contractFat {

    public class ContractJSON {

        public List<Contract> Contract;

    }

    public class Contract { 
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

As an aside, I'd be very careful about naming classes the same as Salesforce types - you might override the type and cause more problems down the line. Maybe something like `ContractWrapper`?